# Installed lxle 14.04.3 64 bit, it is running very slow. What will help?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I have a GT5411E Gateway. Intel Pentium D 914 Dual core 64 bit. Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950. 500G hdd. 2 g of ram. Swap is listed at 3 g and it is on.

This is not dual boot, only Linux.

When I get booted and click on the menu it will take about 45-60 seconds before there is a response. Same with any program I try to run, but some times 2 minutes.

I have updated and gone to Synaptic and upgraded anything that was marked as needing update. I have gone to preferences and stopped almost everything that was on start-up.

I searched Google and have changed cache and memory loading time.

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1992       1522        470        103        191        779
-/+ buffers/cache:        551       1440
Swap:          996          0        996
```

Comment: Try running `top` in a terminal, or running the system monitor tool. Is there anything specific which is using a lot of CPU % ?

Comment: I would imagine iowaits are high. Delays of intermittent length often indicate a failing hard drive. Have you checked the SMART status of your drive as outlined here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04

Comment: @JonasCz I ran top and  the highest CPU% is the browser from 2 to 12% at times. The rest is  .1,  .3 , 1.7%

Comment: @Elder Geek  Yes, thank you. I ran the program and it does not look good .Pre-Fail and Old-Age. Uncorrectable Sector count 127 sectors.  Self-Test Failed.

Comment: @DavidBreeden   Sorry to hear that. Back up all your data ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delays of intermittent length often indicate a failing hard drive. [Check Smart status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04) to be certain. Sadly you may just have to replace the drive. Backup all your critical data as soon as possible as data recovery can be challenging from a failed drive.

Source: Experience